# PHP - i expect some error about undefined object, but there is none, why?

Tags: php, variables

The code is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user->username = "new user";
echo $user->username;
```

I expect some error or warning, but I get none - why?

Comment: E_STRICT, _'Strict standards: Creating default object from empty value in ...'_

Comment: since there is no object declaration. tho it's optional usually - i assumed that E_ALL will do the job (it's a code the i am rewriting, i need the warnings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Will give: "PHP Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value"

> In PHP 5 a new error level E_STRICT is available. As E_STRICT is not included within E_ALL you have to explicitly enable this kind of error level. Enabling E_STRICT during development has some benefits. STRICT messages will help you to use the latest and greatest suggested method of coding, for example warn you about using deprecated functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php